# How to move an entire group of objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move everything contained within the div id "tile", to the center of the web browser. By default the CSS is undefined and it appears on the left side of the browser. What I would like to do is move the entire div to the center using javascript when the button "move" is clicked.

The html is shown directly below, and the attempted (but not working) javascript is shown below that.

html

```
<div id="tile">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="" id="tab4"> Vis </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tabcontent4">Some generic content</div>    
        <button onclick="move();" type="button">Move</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementsById("tile").style.align='center';
```

**EDIT:** How would I move the div to a specific location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS:

```
<div id="tile" style='margin:0 auto;width:300px'>
    ...
</div>
```

Or, put it in a container, and center its content:

```
<div id='container' style='text-align:center'>
  <div id='tile' style='width:300px'>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, non-inline styles are preferred.

Nice username, BTW.

// EDIT

To place the div in a specific location with javascript:

```
document.getElementById('tile').style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById('tile').style.left = "100px";
document.getElementById('tile').style.top = "100px";
```

It must have a `position` defined, usually `absolute` or `relative`.

Once again, this can - and usually should - be done with CSS:

```
#tile { position:absolute; left:100px; top:100px }
```

Comment: I was forgetting the "absolute declaration. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

There is no "align" property in CSS. The closest is [text-align](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_text-align.asp), but you probably want to use the CSS declaration `margin: 0 auto`, which will move the whole `<div>` to the center of the page. So you want:

```
document.getElementById("tile").style.margin="0 auto";
```

Make sure that `tile` has a specified width.

Comment: How would I place the div in a specific location (top:100px, left:100px)?

Comment: Use the same method, except you need to use it three times. The first time, replace the end with `style.position="absolute";`, a second time using `style.top="100px;"`, and a third time using `style.left="100px;"`.